# My calculator program won't work. Problem with String variable

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I am creating a basic calculator with two numbers and an operator. But I can't the the operator to work right. If automatically goes to the else.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class apples {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double first, second, answer;
    String op = "";
    System.out.print("Enter first num: ");
    first = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter second num: ");
    second = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter operator: ");
    op = input.nextLine();

    if(op.equals("-")){
        answer = first-second;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }else if(op.equals("+")){
        answer = first+second;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }else if(op.equals("*")){
        answer = first*second;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }else if(op.equals("/")){
        answer = first/second;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }else{
        System.out.println("crap");
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: doesn't this smell of homework?

Comment: +1 Looks very much like [tag:homework].  hunter it is best to add the homework tag when it is homework.  I'll bet that tag has more followers then the 6 that follow the [tag:if-statement]. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Never compare Strings with ==. Instead use the equals(...) or equalsIgnoreCase(...) method.

The reason that this is important is because == checks if the two objects referred to are one and the same, and you don't really care if stringVariable1 refers to the same object as stringVariable2.  Rather, you want to know if the two variables have Strings that contain the same chars in the same order, and that's what these methods are for, the first if you don't care about capitalization, and the second if you do.

So your code would look more like:

```
if (op.equals("-")){
  answer = first-second;
  System.out.println(answer);
} else if (op.equals("+")){
  answer = first + second;
  System.out.println(answer);
}
//... etc...
```

**Edit**
Problem number two is handling the end of line token.  When you use the nextInt(), nextDouble(), or next() methods of Scanner you have to take care to handle the end of line tokens if the end of line is reached so as not to mess up the next time you call nextLine().

So for instance, if the user enters "10" then return this line of code

```
second = input.nextDouble();
```

well get the 10, but will not "swallow" the end of line token which is left dangling.  So when this line of code is called:

```
op = input.nextLine();
```

the op variable will get the end of line token, and the user won't even be able to enter the "+" op code.  The solution is to take care to swallow the end of line token if it is reached when using a Scanner method that doesn't end with "Line()".

So after nextDouble() call nextLine();.  For example, like so:

```
  String op = "";
  System.out.print("Enter first num: ");
  first = input.nextDouble();
  input.nextLine(); // *** add this to "swallow" the end of line token ***
  System.out.print("Enter second num: ");
  second = input.nextDouble();
  input.nextLine(); // *** add this to "swallow" the end of line token ***

  System.out.print("Enter operator: ");
  op = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: String a = "short"; String b = "short"; a==b.

Comment: That's what I did in my code but it still had the same problem.

Comment: @Stefan: String a = "short"; String b = new String("short"); test these suckers! :)

Comment: @hunter: please show your new code as an edit to your original post.

Comment: I don't understand... what is putting "input.nextLine();" after everything doing?

Comment: the user is not just entering "10", they're entering "10" + return which adds an end of line token to the String. nextDouble() does not swallow this token, so when you call op = nextLine(); all op gets is the hanging end of line token, not the "+" operator that's on the line that follows.

Comment: As an addendum to this answer, you *might* see `==` working correctly in some cases. That is because strings in Java are interned. Don't let that fool you.

Comment: @NullUser: I agree that often == does work, but it's better to use the method(s) that are 100% reliable, and so we recommend use of equals/equalsIgnoreCase. Also it's a good idea to know just what == means for reference variables, not just String.

Comment: @Hovercraft Which exactly what I said ;)

Comment: @Hovercraft: I'm just screwing with you. You gave the base case answer, but I thought I would throw an SCJP monkey wrench into the conversation. ;)

Comment: I'm of the opinion that when you need to compare strings, you switch to scala, groovy, or jruby.

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner.nextLine()` does not work the way that you (or I for that matter) would have expected.  Use `next()` instead.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Apples {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double first, second, answer;
        String op = "";
        System.out.print("Enter first num: ");
        first = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter second num: ");
        second = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter operator: ");
        op = input.next();

        if(op.equals("-")){
            answer = first-second;
            System.out.println(answer);
        }else if(op.equals("+")){
           answer = first+second;
           System.out.println(answer);
        }else if(op.equals("*")){
            answer = first*second;
            System.out.println(answer);
        }else if(op.equals("/")){
            answer = first/second;
            System.out.println(answer);
        }else{
            System.out.println("oops");
        }
        }
    }
```

#### I/O

```
Enter first num: 1.2
Enter second num: 2.3
Enter operator: *
2.76
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Java compare strings with .equals() rather than ==? I think == test for identity, not for equal value.